# MongoDB find document with most matched elements when using $in operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So, I have the next schema, it's an index of car parts that is used to automatically find the part types according to the keywords.

```
nameEnglish: {
  type: String
},
keywords: [{
  type: String
}]
```

I have two documents on the database, one is:

```
[
  { _id: 1, nameEnglish: 'abcdef', keywords: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] },
  { _id: 2, nameEnglish: 'cde', keywords: ['c', 'd', 'e'] }
]
```

What I am want to do now is query this collection with the **MOST** number of matched keywords.

```
myArr = ['b', 'c', 'f'];
db.collection.find({ keywords: { $in: myArr } });
```

I want this to always return the first document, since it has 3 matched keywords, and the second has only one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation using `$setIntersection` to find the matching elements between `keywords` array and input array followed by `$size` to count the matching elements and `$sort` descending and `$limit` 1 to output the most matched document.

You can drop the count field using project exclusion `{$project:{count:0}}` as final stage.

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [{
        $addFields: {
            "count": {
                $size: {
                    $setIntersection: ["$keywords", myArr]
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            "count": -1
        }
    }, {
        $limit: 1
    }]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use aggregation with `$setIntersection` to get the number of matches, and sort by the no of matches, limit to expected number of results.

```
db.col.aggregate([
{$addFields : {noOfMatch :{$size :{$setIntersection : ["$keywords", ['b', 'c', 'f']]}}}},
{$sort : {"noOfMatch" : -1}},
{$limit : 1}
])
```